# How to get Total CPU usage percentage without instance name in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average 
 I will get output like 
 Average 
 -----------
30
how can i get that value 30 only .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get just the value, ccess the `Average` propert of `Measure-Object`'s output. No need to pipe the results to  `Select-Object` at all. Like so,

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average).Average
8
```